# Why am I NOT getting an error when I test password validation?

Tags: ios, swift, regex, validation, google-cloud-firestore

As you can likely tell by this question I'm new to iOS/programming: I'm trying to implement password validation in which the user input must be at least **8 characters, contain 1 upper case letter, 1 lower case letter, 1 number, and 1 special character**. I decided to use a regex and an extension on UIViewController to do this. **I read somewhere that I have to include this outside of my "SignUpViewController" scope (not sure why)** which is what I've done. **The db does have open read/write rules since I'm still testing things** so is that the reason it's not checking for this validation and signing up the user every time? Please help

Below is the code:

```
import UIKit
import Firebase



class SignUpViewController: UIViewController {

    //Outlets
    @IBOutlet weak var firstNameText: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var lastNameText: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var emailText: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var passwordText: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var signUpButton: UIButton!


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }


    @IBAction func signUpButtonTapped(_ sender: Any) {
        guard let firstName = firstNameText.text,
            let lastName = lastNameText.text,
            let email = emailText.text else { return }
            guard emailText.containsValidEmail() else {
            print("Invalid email. Please try again.")
            return
        }
            let password = passwordText.text else { return }
            guard passwordText.containsValidPassword() else {
            print("Invalid password. Please try again.")
            return
        }

        Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: email, password: password) { (authResult, error) in
            if let error = error {
                debugPrint("Error creating user: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            }
            let changeRequest = Auth.auth().currentUser?.createProfileChangeRequest()
            changeRequest?.displayName = firstName
            changeRequest?.commitChanges(completion: { (error) in
                if let error = error {
                    debugPrint(error.localizedDescription)
                }
            })
            guard let userId = authResult?.user else { return }
            let userData: [String: Any] = [
                "firstName" : "",
                "lastName" : "",
                "User ID" : userId,
                "dateCreated" : FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
                ]
            let db = Firestore.firestore()
            db.collection("users").document("one").setData(userData) { err in
                if let err = err {
                    print("Error writing document: \(err)")
                } else {
                    print("Document successfully written!")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
public extension UITextField {
    func containsValidPassword() -> Bool {
        let passwordRegex = "^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\\d)(?=.*[d$@$!%*?&#])[A-Za-z\\dd$@$!%*?&#]{8,}"
        return NSPredicate(format: "SELF MATCHES %@", passwordRegex).evaluate(with: self.text)
    }
}
public extension UITextField {
    func containsValidEmail() -> Bool {
    let emailRegex = "[A-Z0-9a-z._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Za-z]{2,64}"
    return NSPredicate(format: "SELF MATCHES %@", emailRegex).evaluate(with: self.text)
    }
}
```

**UPDATE 12/14:
I edited the original post by adding extensions for password and email validation. I added password validation by using an extension on UITextField. However, when I try to do the same for the email I get compile errors. Why is this?**

Comment: Where is called `isValidPassword()`? Also, strangely, you do `evaluate(with: self)`, but `self` is a `UIViewController`, not a `String`. Did you meant `extension String{}` instead, and in that case the `self` is correct, or `isValidPassword(_ string: String) -> Bool { ... return ... evaluate(with: string) }`?

Comment: I don't see you call isValidPassword() anywhere. Also you need to pass a string param in there.

Comment: Both you and David mentioned not calling the function (rookie mistake!). Currently I'm going with the approach of extending the UITextField since using a function that passes a string is giving me tons of errors @Larme

Comment: I'm calling containsValidPassword() now and could you help explain why when I try to pass a string param, I get so many compile errors? @Dare

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you're not calling the `isValidPassword` function anywhere in your code. Secondly, if you'd actually call it, it would cause a runtime exception, since you'd be trying to pass a `UIViewController` instance to an `NSPredicate` to match on a regex.

You should rather define `isValidPassword` on `UITextField` and validate its `text` property. (I'd also rename the function to `containsValidPassword` in this case, since the `UITextField` isn't a password, it just contains the String for the password.)

```
extension UITextField {
    func containsValidPassword() -> Bool {
        let passwordRegex = "^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\\d)(?=.*[d$@$!%*?&#])[A-Za-z\\dd$@$!%*?&#]{8,}"
        return NSPredicate(format: "SELF MATCHES %@", passwordRegex).evaluate(with: self.text)
    }
}
```

Then you also need to call the validation:

```
@IBAction func signUpButtonTapped(_ sender: Any) {
    guard let firstName = firstNameText.text,
        let lastName = lastNameText.text,
        let email = emailText.text,
        let password = passwordText.text else { return }
    guard passwordText.containsValidPassword() else { 
        // Let the user know that their pwd is incorrect
        return
    }
...
```

Comment: I edited the original post by adding extensions for password and email validation. I added password validation by using an extension on UITextField. However, when I tried to do the same for email I got compile errors. Why is this? @Dávid Pásztor

Comment: @CadenJoe you miss a `guard` before `let password...`

Comment: @CadenJoe if you found any of the answers helpful, you should consider marking one of them as the accepted answer

Answer (score 0):

You're evaluating your predicate with `self` where `self` is of type `UIViewController` (that's what you're extending), you've probably meant to extend `String` instead.

```
extension String {
    func isValidPassword() -> Bool {
        let passwordRegex = "^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\\d)(?=.*[d$@$!%*?&#])[A-Za-z\\dd$@$!%*?&#]{8,}"
        return NSPredicate(format: "SELF MATCHES %@", passwordRegex).evaluate(with: self)
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
let isValidPassword = "something".isValidPassword()
```

Actually I'm not sure if extensions suit this condition, I would recommend you to create a simple function inside your `SignUpViewController`-

```
func isValidPassword(password: String) -> Bool {
    let passwordRegex = "^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\\d)(?=.*[d$@$!%*?&#])[A-Za-z\\dd$@$!%*?&#]{8,}"
    return NSPredicate(format: "SELF MATCHES %@", passwordRegex).evaluate(with: password)
}
```

Or if you want to be more specific-

```
func isValidPassword() -> Bool{
    guard let password = passwordText.text else { return false }

    let passwordRegex = "^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\\d)(?=.*[d$@$!%*?&#])[A-Za-z\\dd$@$!%*?&#]{8,}"
    return NSPredicate(format: "SELF MATCHES %@", passwordRegex).evaluate(with: password)
}
```

Comment: Could you help me understand why when I try to pass a string param in a func, I get so many compile errors? That's why I've been using the extension on UITextField @Niv

Comment: I was missing a guard statement by let password. Runs as expected! Errors gone! Might use a protocol approach instead  @Niv

Answer (score 0):

```
import UIKit
import Firebase



class SignUpViewController: UIViewController {

    //Outlets
    @IBOutlet weak var firstNameText: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var lastNameText: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var emailText: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var passwordText: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var signUpButton: UIButton!


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }


    @IBAction func signUpButtonTapped(_ sender: Any) {
        guard let firstName = firstNameText.text,
            let lastName = lastNameText.text,
            let email = emailText.text else { return }
            guard emailText.containsValidEmail() else {
            print("Invalid email/password. Please try again.")
            return
        }
            guard let password = passwordText.text else { return }
            guard passwordText.containsValidPassword() else {
            print("Invalid email/password. Please try again.")
            return
        }

        Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: email, password: password) { (authResult, error) in
            if let error = error {
                debugPrint("Error creating user: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            }
            let changeRequest = Auth.auth().currentUser?.createProfileChangeRequest()
            changeRequest?.displayName = firstName
            changeRequest?.commitChanges(completion: { (error) in
                if let error = error {
                    debugPrint(error.localizedDescription)
                }
            })
            guard let userId = authResult?.user else { return }
            let userData: [String: Any] = [
                "firstName" : "",
                "lastName" : "",
                "User ID" : userId,
                "dateCreated" : FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
                ]
            let db = Firestore.firestore()
            db.collection("users").document("one").setData(userData) { err in
                if let err = err {
                    print("Error writing document: \(err)")
                } else {
                    print("Document successfully written!")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
public extension UITextField {
    func containsValidPassword() -> Bool {
        let passwordRegex = "^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\\d)(?=.*[d$@$!%*?&#])[A-Za-z\\dd$@$!%*?&#]{8,}"
        return NSPredicate(format: "SELF MATCHES %@", passwordRegex).evaluate(with: self.text)
    }
}
public extension UITextField {
    func containsValidEmail() -> Bool {
        let emailRegex = "[A-Z0-9a-z._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Za-z]{2,64}"
        return NSPredicate(format: "SELF MATCHES %@", emailRegex).evaluate(with: self.text)
    }
}
```

This format runs as expected. Thank you